# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) where expecting more then zero rows

Tags: mysql

```
  SELECT username FROM `info` WHERE id
  in ('919953990950_1403180247868.707, 
919953990950_1403239797121.525,
919953990950_1403241821083.838,
919953990950_1403248486971.661,
919953990950_1403248511255.484,
919953990950_1403248860947.79,
919953990950_1403255594277.013') and username !='1403176452487620892' limit 50
```

this is not selecting rows what's wrong in my query?

Comment: How did you input value for `IN(...)`? Are the numbers a `group concat` result? If yes, use `find_in_set( id, csv_nums )` over `in( csv_nums )`

Comment: @Ravinder i am inserting it by scala language thats a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose each value in single quotes, not the entire list:

```
  SELECT username
  FROM `info`
  WHERE id in ('919953990950_1403180247868.707', 
               '919953990950_1403239797121.525',
               '919953990950_1403241821083.838',
               '919953990950_1403248486971.661',
               '919953990950_1403248511255.484',
               '919953990950_1403248860947.79',
               '919953990950_1403255594277.013'
              ) and
       username <> '1403176452487620892'
  limit 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by putting every value in `quotes ''` else it would consider the entire as one string and also replace `!=` with `<>`:

```
SELECT username
  FROM `info`
  WHERE id
  in ('919953990950_1403180247868.707', 
      '919953990950_1403239797121.525',
      '919953990950_1403241821083.838',
      '919953990950_1403248486971.661',
      '919953990950_1403248511255.484',
      '919953990950_1403248860947.79',
      '919953990950_1403255594277.013') and username <>'1403176452487620892'
```

Comment: `!=` and `<>` are both the _not equal operator_, see [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Answer (score 1):

OP's comment:

> *i am inserting it by scala language thats a string*

Use `find_in_set` when set of values are in the form of a *comma separated values*

```
SELECT username FROM `info` 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET( id, csv_values )
   AND username !='1403176452487620892' limit 50;
```

In the above example replace `'csv_values'` with the string of values received from *SCALA*
I suggest you to go with Prepared Statement to bind values.

**Refer to**:

- [***FIND_IN_SET( str, strlist )***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

  - Return the index position of the first argument within the second
    argument